# Rendering form from Entry Field

Tags: craft3, form, plugin-freeform

I'm trying to pass an entry field type "Formfield" into a template. I have it working without passing any custom values through but when I do it outside of the render tag, No matter what I do I am getting an error saying null variable cannot render.  Thoughts?

ie: (Below works)

```
{{ entry.contactFormHandle.render() }}
```

But: (Does Not) in many variables and difference does not...

```
{{ craft.freeform.form("{entry.contactFormHandle}", {
                        labelClass: "my-label-class",
                        inputClass: "my-input-class",
                        submitClass: "my-button-class",
                        instructionsBelowField: true,
                        overrideValues: {}
                    }).render() }}
```

I'm sure it's something stupid. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange! Yes, your syntax is wrong - you need to remove the curly brackets around entry.contactForm.handle, and the quotations, and actually get the handle.

```
{{ craft.freeform.form( entry.contactForm.handle,
    {
        instructionsBelowField: true
    }
).render() }}
```

Source: [Freeform docs](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/template-functions/freeform.form.html#parameters)

Comment: I tried this, but it actually returns the same error where it's trying to render a null variable.

"Impossible to invoke a method ("render") on a null variable."

Comment: I've updated my answer; and you'll also want to wrap it in a conditional to make sure the form exists before you try to get it's handle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need `entry.contactFormHandle.handle`. Freeform's form select field doesn't select the form handle, it selects the *form*, so you need to get more specific in drilling down to the handle.